# Using std::bad_alloc for C pointers

Tags: c++, exception, memory

I'm using a library written in C in a C++ project.

I'd like to use C++ exceptions to handle C errors. In particular, it would be nice to have an exception thrown if an allocation fails.

I can do this in constructors of classes which hold C-style pointers to C structs :

```
if (c_object == NULL)
    throw std::bad_alloc();
```

But if the class is responsible for several C objects they are no ways of free-ing all already allocated pointers since the destructor isn't called.

I have a feeling I could use smart-pointers, but I don't have much experience with them. What's more, I have to have access to the original C pointers to use the C api properly.

Is there an elegant solution to this ?

Comment: C++ RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization) and only manage 1 resource per class.

Comment: If I do this, I basically end up writing a C++ wrapper for the C library. I'm hopping there's an easier solution :/

Comment: You always have exactly one unmanaged resource per class, everything else is extremely error-prone and becomes unmaintanable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been already mentioned in the comments, I merely repeat it as an answer:

> But if the class is responsible for several C objects they are no ways of free-ing all already allocated pointers since the destructor isn't called.

That is correct. Because of this and the single-responsibility principle, each C++ class manages at most one unmanaged resource ("C object" in your case). And those classes that do manage a resource do absolutely nothing else.

If you use a smart pointer, you do exactly that: the smart pointer class manages access to a single type of resource, namely, heap objects usually allocated with `new` (the latter can be customized). If that would help you, feel free to use a smart pointer, which is completely fine, but never write a class that manages more than one raw resource.

Comment: Are you saying @a1ex07 answer is bad then ?

Comment: @otibom: Yes. You should always follow SRP and use smart pointers- this is what they are for and they do this job excellently.

Comment: @otibom: if you handle multiple raw resource in one class, you always have to keep track which are valid. I prefer UncleBens's solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can store each pointer in a smart pointer like `shared_ptr`. Those also accept (optionally) a pointer to a deallocation function.

To throw exceptions, you can wrap each allocation function.

```
//the api functions

Foo* CreateFoo(Bar);

void DestroyFoo(const Foo*);

//wrapped with
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> CppCreateFoo(Bar bar)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Foo> new_foo(CreateFoo(bar), &DestroyFoo);
    if (!new_foo) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    return new_foo;
}

//underlying pointer accessed with
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> smart_foo_ptr = CppCreateFoo(bar);
UseFooPtr(smart_foo_pointer.get());
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use `try -catch` block in constructor ?

```
A::A() : c_object(0), c1_object(0), c2_object(0)
{
    try 
    {
       c_object = getCObject();
       if (!c_object)
         throw std::bad_alloc();
       c1_object = getCObject1();
       if (!c1_ojbect)
          throw std::bad_alloc();
        //.....
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc& )
    {
        if (c_object) 
          releasCObjectMemory(c_object);
        if (c1_object)
          releasCObjectMemory(c1_object);
        //....
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to trivially achieve what basically is NOT trivially achievable. 
In any case, I think it's best to decide between the following two approaches

1. for each struct, write a C++ wrapper
2. follow C approach without exceptions (as is now)

I don't think you can achieve the effect of 1 with no effort of option 2 :)

HTH